# How to make these calls in C#

Tags: c#, watchdog

Can anyone tell me how I would make these calls from C# under Windows 8 ?

As I understand it I would need a device driver of some that I can call from my application.  If there is any other way to achieve the same thing I would appreciate some advice.

And if you are wondering it's to control the hardware watchdog timer.

Thanks

```
#include “math.h”
#include “stdio.h”
#include “dos.h”

#define SIO_INDEX    0x4E       /* or index = 0x2E  */
#define SIO_DATA     0x4F       /* or data  = 0x2F  */

/* Example */

void main()
{

outportb(SIO_INDEX, 0x87);  /* SIO - Enable */
outportb(SIO_INDEX, 0x87); 

outportb(SIO_INDEX, 0x07);  /* LDN - WDT */
outportb(SIO_DATA,  0x07); 

outportb(SIO_INDEX, 0x28);  /* GPIO12/WDTRST# function select */
outportb(SIO_DATA,  0x00);  /* The pin function is WDTRST#    */

outportb(SIO_INDEX, 0x30);  /* WDT - enable */
outportb(SIO_DATA,  0x01);  

outportb(SIO_INDEX, 0xF0);  /* WDOUT - enable */
outportb(SIO_DATA,  0x80);  

outportb(SIO_INDEX, 0xF6);  /* WDT - Timeout Value: 5sec */
outportb(SIO_DATA,  0x05);  

outportb(SIO_INDEX, 0xF5);  /* WDT - Configuration */
outportb(SIO_DATA,  0x31);  

outportb(SIO_INDEX, 0xAA);  /* SIO - Disable */
```

EDIT

I found a good explanation here which helped understand what all the hex numbers mean when used with outportb() and Hogan's answer shows how to sent the data to the port.

http://retired.beyondlogic.org/serial/serial.htm#12

However I am still unclear on how I convert the SIO_INDEX 0x4E, which I assume is the port address of the WDT to a SerialPort name.  I will check the device config settings to see if there is anything in there showing the port address but not near the device at the moment to do so.

BTW I have used the SerialPort API extensively so don't think I need any help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SerialPort.Write.

Your code would look something like this:

```
myport = new SerialPort();

myport.PortName = SetPortName( /* value here */);
myport.BaudRate = SetPortBaudRate( /* value here */);
myport.Parity = SetPortParity( /* value here */);
myport.DataBits = SetPortDataBits( /* value here */);
myport.StopBits = SetPortStopBits( /* value here */);
myport.Handshake = SetPortHandshake( /* value here */);

myport.Open();

byte[] buff = new byte[2];
wBuff[0] =  0x87;
wBuff[1] =  0x87;
myport.Write(wBuff, 0, 2);
```

See the microsoft docs here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143551%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

See some good example code here: http://www.helloapps.com/MF/SPL/cs_serial/serialport_sample2.html

Comment: What port would I use?

Comment: I don't know, but you can use `string[] serialPorts = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();` to get the names

Comment: Are you sure the sample code is writing to a serial port?

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald - That question makes no sense to me.  Did you read the linked pages?  `outportb` writes to a serial port. This code writes to a serial port.  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Confused because the WDT is built into the motherboard, and it just occurred to me now that even so it may in fact be attached to a serial port - duh.  Thanks for the kick start :-)  sorry was in a world where it had to be plugged in to an external port to be a serial device.